# Unity - Cube edges are jagged

Tags: unity

I am new to Unity. I have a basic setup following Brackeys tutorial. When in game mode, I see the red cube having jagged edges. I tried increasing the antialiasing in Unity to 8x but it did not work. I also tried turning on antialiasing in my Nvidia control panel. But the issue still persists.

[image]